# Spring boot cxf schema Location properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, cxf

I'm using cxf with spring boot, my EndpointImpl is as follows:

```
@Bean
    public Endpoint serviceEndpoint() throws IOException {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), nameWSImpl());

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("schema-validation-enabled", false);
        properties.put("mtom-enabled", true);
        endpoint.setProperties(properties);

        endpoint.setDataBinding(new XmlBeansDataBinding());
        JaxWsServiceFactoryBean jrxw = new JaxWsServiceFactoryBean();
        jrxw.setWrapped(false);
        endpoint.setServiceFactory(jrxw);

        List<String> schemaLocations = new ArrayList<String>();
        schemaLocations.add("classpath:/xsd/schema-types.xsd");

        endpoint.setSchemaLocations(schemaLocations);

        endpoint.publish("/NamesWSService");
        return endpoint;
    }
```

I'm getting the follwing error when i run the MyApp.jar, my xsd seems correct where i imported in it another xsd with :

```
<xs:import namespace="http://..../1.0" schemaLocation="schema-mn.xsd"/>
```

> Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException:
>   org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: There was
>   an error reading the schema classpath:/xsd/schema-types.xsd.  at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:375)    at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:255)  at
>   pakge.configuration.WebServiceConfig.serviceEndpoint(WebServiceConfig.java:82)
>     at
>   pakge.configuration.WebServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94ee36aa.CGLIB$serviceEndpoint$0()
>     at
>   pakge.configuration.WebServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94ee36aa$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8f1a2871.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
>     at
>   pakge.configuration.WebServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94ee36aa.serviceEndpoint()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>     ... 27 common frames omitted

How can i deal with this error?

Comment: So where did you place xsd file?

Comment: in src/main/resources of my spring boot app